# box-shadow CSS property not working properly on iOS

Tags: css, ios, html5-video, box-shadow

```js
function getLocation(parameter) {
    const queryString = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const queryStringParam = queryString.get(parameter);
    return queryStringParam;
};

function fillServiceItemContent(parameter, element, infoArray, elementTitle) {
    const locationParam = getLocation(parameter);
    const info = infoArray[locationParam].info;
    const title = infoArray[locationParam].title;
    const video = infoArray[locationParam].video;

    if (elementTitle === undefined && element.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.setAttribute('src', video);
        element.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');
        return;
    } else if(elementTitle === undefined) {
        element.innerHTML = info;
        return;
    }
        element.innerHTML = info;
        elementTitle.innerHTML = title;
};
```

```css
.service-items .service-video video {
    height: 80vh;
    border-radius: 1em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
        -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: -15px 14px 23px -16px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -15px 14px 23px -16px #000;
        -moz-box-shadow: -15px 14px 23px -16px #000;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-items">
  <div class="service-video">
  <video id="service-video-source" autoplay loop muted playsinline></video>
</div>
```

I have a problem with the box-shadow rendering on a video tag on iOS. It's not working properly neither on Safari or Chrome. I have tested it on iPhone X. It's pushing the video to the right, and the box-shadow is invisible. On desktop or Android is working properly. Is there a solution for this?

[image]